# How to find out the (current) free memory on the system?

Tags: memory

Is there any way in Mathematica to find out the currently free memory on the system Mathematica runs on (like the utility `free` shows on the command line)? I've found out functions to show the memory occupied by Mathematica itself, but of course there are also other programs running on the system, taking their share of memory, so that number is not sufficient to estimate the free memory.

The background is that currently if I do something which might fill up my memory (and I don't forget to do it),  I call `free` by hand, subtract a safety margin, and then use `MemoryConstrained` in order to prevent the memory to get completely filled up (with quite unpleasant consequences). I'd like to automate that. While I certainly could call `free` from Mathematica and parse its output for the number, I'd like to avoid that if I can (who knows if the next system update makes subtle changes to `free` and then the parsing fails to give the correct number).

Comment: this seems os-specific. maybe tag it as such if it is

Comment: Well, `MemoryInUse[]` is the polar opposite of `free`, I'd say...

Comment: @acl: Well, the concept of free memory is certainly not OS specific. The `free` utility is, but I'm after a Mathematica function (if it exists) which most likely wouldn't be (I don't think there is any OS Mathematica runs on where you cannot get an estimate of available memory). Of course, if none exists, my workaround (parsing output of `free`) would be OS specific, but that's not what I asked for (although if someone wants to write it for me, I wouldn't complain :-)). So the OS-independent answer would be either "The function is called so-and-so and used like this" or "There isn't any."

Comment: @R.M: I'd not expect Mathematica to add memory of all processes (I strongly doubt `free` does that either). I think that every OS will have some functionality to estimate free memory (guarantees cannot be given anyway because right after returning, another process might allocate memory), and I'd expect Mathematica to use that functionality.

Comment: It may or may not be possible to use J/Link for this.

Comment: fair enough. I doubt there is an OS-independent way of doing it, though.

Comment: @R.M: Importing and then parsing the text is what I'll have to resort to if Mathematica doesn't have a suitable function, yes. I hoped to avoid that. (BTW, I've now found that `/proc/meminfo` contains the information in a more parse-friendly format, so I'll probably use that if I have to go the system-dependent way).

Comment: on OS X (and I imagine other BSD systems, although I may be wrong), parsing the output of `top -l 1| grep PhysMem` is probably the easiest way to go (`sysctl` is the closest thing I know of to `/proc/`, but I am not very familiar with it)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You might be able to use `JLink` along with some undocumented behaviour of the Java class `java.lang.management.ManagementFactory` to get the information you seek:

```
Needs["JLink`"]
InstallJava[];
LoadJavaClass["java.lang.management.ManagementFactory"];
JavaBlock[
  {#, java`lang`management`ManagementFactory`getOperatingSystemMXBean[]@#[]} & /@
  { getName
  , getArch
  , getVersion
  , getCommittedVirtualMemorySize
  , getFreePhysicalMemorySize
  , getFreeSwapSpaceSize
  , getTotalPhysicalMemorySize
  , getTotalSwapSpaceSize
  , getProcessCpuTime
  , getAvailableProcessors
  , getSystemLoadAverage
  } // Grid
]
```

This works on Windows 7 (Mathematica 8, 64-bit):

```
Out[368]= getName                        Windows Vista
          getArch                        amd64
          getVersion                     6.1
          getCommittedVirtualMemorySize  102449152
          getFreePhysicalMemorySize      5997510656
          getFreeSwapSpaceSize           14498115584
          getTotalPhysicalMemorySize     8587284480
          getTotalSwapSpaceSize          17172676608
          getProcessCpuTime              6068438900
          getAvailableProcessors         4
          getSystemLoadAverage           -1.
```

I don't have Mac or Linux boxes to hand at the moment to test whether it works there as well.

Comment: it works fine on OS X (your system is not only not being loaded, but in fact actively doing negative work???)

Comment: @acl Thanks for checking OS X.  As for the negative work, everybody complains about the heat death of the universe but few do anything about it ;)

Comment: Do you know why this shows *Windows Vista* and *amd64*?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Windows 7 is a really just a marketing label slapped on a Vista release.  It would seem that the name change happened too late to change it in the deepest parts of the OS.  "amd64" is the name given to the original 64-bit instructions added to the x86 architecture.  The name has stuck, although the term "x86-64" is sometimes used as a vendor-neutral term.  It so happens that this workstation has an Intel CPU, not an AMD one, but the historical term is used nonetheless.

Comment: I've just checked on Linux, it works there as well. Moreover, the output is a Grid instead of simply a string, thus parsing isn't necessary either. I've changed the accepted answer to yours.

Comment: Actually I hadn't carefully read your solution previously; now I recognized that the grid is only your addition for demonstration, and I can get the desired values directly. Which is even better. :-)

Comment: One additional point I noticed now: To execute it directly on the kernel (i.e. without the notebook interface) one additionally has to execute `InstallJava[]` before using `LoadJavaClass`.

Comment: @celtschk I added `InstallJava[]` to the response for good measure.

Comment: @WReach There was a report (see Emmanuel Bourg's comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/47199/59038)) that this method does not allow to "see" more than 2 Gb of physical memory on Windows XP (probably it is true only for 32bit systems and the reason is a limitation of Java itself).

Answer (score 6):

Under Windows you can use `NETLink` for this (it requires Microsoft .NET v.2 or later to be installed). Two methods were discussed in this MathGroups thread: ["Calling kernel.dll from Mathematica. 1"](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/CECRZekCGdU/DvLEi3_GLa4J), ["Calling kernel.dll from Mathematica. 2"](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/FKeu0AKzKoQ).

One way is to get this information via a managed API (that is, in .NET itself):

```
Needs["NETLink`"]
query = NETNew["System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher", 
   "SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem"];
resultCollection = query@Get[];
mo = First[NETObjectToExpression[resultCollection]];
getFreePhysMemNet[] := (mo@Get[]; mo["FreePhysicalMemory"])
```

The function `getFreePhysMemNet[]` returns the amount of free physical memory in Kb. This method is 30 times slower than direct calling of the `GlobalMemoryStatusEx` function of kernel32.dll which is availiable both on 32 bit and 64 bit Windows systems (checked under Windows 7 x64). Here is the code:

```
Needs["NETLink`"];
getFreePhysMem::internalError = 
  "globalMemoryStatusEx[memorystatusex] has not returned True.";
If[$OperatingSystem === "Windows", 
      memorystatusex = Symbol["LoadedNETTypes"][];
      globalMemoryStatusEx = 
       Symbol["DefineDLLFunction"][
        "[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
                public class MEMORYSTATUSEX
                {public uint dwLength;
                public uint dwMemoryLoad;
                public ulong ullTotalPhys;
                public ulong ullAvailPhys;
                public ulong ullTotalPageFile;
                public ulong ullAvailPageFile;
                public ulong ullTotalVirtual;
                public ulong ullAvailVirtual;
                public ulong ullAvailExtendedVirtual;
                public MEMORYSTATUSEX()
                {this.dwLength = (uint) 
                Marshal.SizeOf(typeof( MEMORYSTATUSEX ));}}
                [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
                [DllImport(\"kernel32.dll\", CharSet=CharSet.Auto,     \
    SetLastError=true)]
                public static extern bool GlobalMemoryStatusEx([In, Out]  \
       MEMORYSTATUSEX lpBuffer);"];
      memorystatusex = 
       Complement[Symbol["LoadedNETTypes"][], memorystatusex][[1, 1]];
      memorystatusex = memorystatusex <> "+MEMORYSTATUSEX";
      memorystatusex = Symbol["NETNew"][memorystatusex];
      getFreePhysMem[] := 
       If[TrueQ[globalMemoryStatusEx[memorystatusex]], 
        memorystatusex@ullAvailPhys, 
        Message[getFreePhysMem::internalError]; Abort[]; $Failed]];
```

The function `getFreePhysMem[]` returns the amount of free physical memory in bytes.

Timings:

```
In[10]:= Do[getFreePhysMemNet[], {100}] // AbsoluteTiming
Do[getFreePhysMem[], {100}] // AbsoluteTiming
%%/%

Out[10]= {1.9218750, Null}

Out[11]= {0.0625000, Null}

Out[12]= {30.7500, 1}
```

Answer (score 6):

On Windows with an [external call](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490960.aspx):

```
ReadList["!typeperf \"\\Memory\\Available Bytes\" -sc 1", Word, 
   RecordLists -> True, WordSeparators -> {","}] // ToExpression@Part[#,2,2]&
```

Comment: +1. Great! But it does not work for localized versions of Windows: words "Memory" and "Available Bytes" are localized and English version does not work. For getting localized names one can use the `typeperf -qx` command.

Answer (score 5):

Since Mathematica runs on only a few different OS's, why not write a little conditional expression that, for each OS, feeds to a shell the corresponding command that returns the amount of free memory.

The trouble, of course, is that not all OS's are equal in this regard. I don't know of a Mac OS X built-in command equivalent to the Linux `free`, but you can locate Python scripts that will do the equivalent thing.

Comment: Given that until now nobody has told me one, I have to conclude that there's indeed no ready-made Mathematica function (or if there is, it's so hidden in undocumented internals that nobody knows about it), therefore I accept your answer as the right one.

Answer (score 2):

Well,for the efficiency I will give a new version:

```
Last[ReadList["!wmic OS get FreePhysicalMemory"]]
```

PS:I just test it in my windows 10.You can check it in your environment.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a Mac, you can call the external command `vm_stat` with [`RunProcess`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RunProcess.html):

```
RunProcess["vm_stat"]
```

[image]

We can extract the relevant data in lines 1 and 2 to get the available memory on the system. Here it is packed into a function:

```
AvailableSystemMemory[] /; $OperatingSystem == "MacOSX" :=
  Module[{call, vmstat, bytesperpage, pagesfree},

    call = RunProcess["vm_stat"];
    vmstat = call["StandardOutput"];

    (
        bytesperpage = StringCases[vmstat, "(page size of " ~~ x__ ~~ " bytes)" :> Quantity[ToExpression[x], "Bytes"]];
        pagesfree = StringCases[vmstat, "Pages free:" ~~ Shortest[x__] ~~ "\n" :> ToExpression[x]];

        (
            UnitConvert[First[bytesperpage pagesfree], "Gigabytes"]

        ) /; Length[bytesperpage] == Length[pagesfree] == 1

    ) /; call["ExitCode"] == 0 && call["StandardError"] == "" && StringQ[vmstat]
  ]
```

Memory available on my machine:

```
AvailableSystemMemory[]
```

> ```
> Quantity[8.42319, "Gigabytes"]
> ```