# Aborting evaluation when the memory exceeds a certain limit

Tags: memory, kernel

Sometimes when generating a lot of data the memory usage shoots beyond its physical realm and my laptop freezes. There is no way to stop Mathematica when this happens. Task manager (or its equivalent in other OSes) won't even start.

I was wondering if it's possible to set a threshold somewhere in Mathematica to stop it automatically after a certain amount of memory.

Comment: If it is due to lots of intermediary calculations, setting `$HistoryLength =0` could lead to using less memory.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Since one may not always accurately predict when `MemoryContrained` is needed, I recommend setting up a watch-dog task.  Belisarius described how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7862223/618728) in answer to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7854980/618728).  I will reproduce it below as answers that are merely links are discouraged.

---

> In *Mathematica* 8 you could start a memory watchdog, something along
>   the lines of:
>
> ```
> maxMemAllowed        = 1.3 1024^3; (*1.3 GB*);
> intervalBetweenTests = 1; (*seconds*)
> iAmAliveSignal       = 0;
> Dynamic[iAmAliveSignal]
> RunScheduledTask[
>        If[MemoryInUse[] > maxMemAllowed , Quit[], iAmAliveSignal++],      
>        intervalBetweenTests];
> ```
>
> Remember to run
>
> ```
> RemoveScheduledTask[ScheduledTasks[]];
> ```
>
> to disable it.

Comment: Are you actually using this in practice?

Comment: @Szabolcs no, I don't have version 8. :-/  If belisarius cares to post his own answer I will delete mine.

Comment: I didn't realize this was v8 functionality.  You might want to try ``?Internal`*Periodical*``.  I'm not sure if those `Internal` functions exist in v7, but they seem to provide very similar (the same?) functionality.  I can't recall how to use them, but it should be easy to figure out.

Comment: Ha! Nice answer!

Answer (score 15):

In addition to [Mr.Wizard's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2803/280).

In many cases it is very practical to stop the evaluation when the actual amount of free *physical* memory in your system becomes less than specified threshold. You can get the amount of free physical memory very efficiently via `NETLink` call to `GlobalMemoryStatusEx` function of kernel32.dll (which is available both under 32 bit and 64 bit Windows systems). Here I define `getFreePhysMem[]` function which returns the current amount of free physical memory:

```
Needs["NETLink`"];
getFreePhysMem::internalError = 
  "globalMemoryStatusEx[memorystatusex] has not returned True.";
If[$OperatingSystem === "Windows", 
  memorystatusex = Symbol["LoadedNETTypes"][];
  globalMemoryStatusEx = 
   Symbol["DefineDLLFunction"][
    "[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
            public class MEMORYSTATUSEX
            {public uint dwLength;
            public uint dwMemoryLoad;
            public ulong ullTotalPhys;
            public ulong ullAvailPhys;
            public ulong ullTotalPageFile;
            public ulong ullAvailPageFile;
            public ulong ullTotalVirtual;
            public ulong ullAvailVirtual;
            public ulong ullAvailExtendedVirtual;
            public MEMORYSTATUSEX()
            {this.dwLength = (uint) 
            Marshal.SizeOf(typeof( MEMORYSTATUSEX ));}}
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            [DllImport(\"kernel32.dll\", CharSet=CharSet.Auto,     \
SetLastError=true)]
            public static extern bool GlobalMemoryStatusEx([In, Out]  \
   MEMORYSTATUSEX lpBuffer);"];
  memorystatusex = 
   Complement[Symbol["LoadedNETTypes"][], memorystatusex][[1, 1]];
  memorystatusex = memorystatusex <> "+MEMORYSTATUSEX";
  memorystatusex = Symbol["NETNew"][memorystatusex];
  getFreePhysMem[] := 
   If[TrueQ[globalMemoryStatusEx[memorystatusex]], 
    memorystatusex@ullAvailPhys, 
    Message[getFreePhysMem::internalError]; Abort[]; $Failed]];
```

Timings:

```
Do[getFreePhysMem[], {100}] // AbsoluteTiming
(*=> {0.0312500, Null}*)
```

More information on this function: ["Calling kernel.dll from Mathematica. 1"](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/CECRZekCGdU/DvLEi3_GLa4J), ["Calling kernel.dll from Mathematica. 2"](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/FKeu0AKzKoQ).

Comment: QAlexey Thanks for this detailed answer. It Sure gives me enough code to ponder about :).

Comment: @Lou There is [another method with `JavaLink`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/459/280). You may be also interested in this discussion: "[Self-restarting MathKernel - is it possible in Mathematica?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7864643/590388)".

Comment: Could this be expanded to OS X?

Comment: @shrx I don't use OS X but you could try [the JavaLink solution](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/459/280).

Answer (score 12):

You can make use of either [`TimeConstrained`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TimeConstrained.html) or [`MemoryConstrained`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MemoryConstrained.html) to terminate evaluation when it runs out of time or memory respectively.

For example, if you have a function that has a reasonable memory footprint, but takes time to evaluate, you can abort evaluation after a certain amount of time (in seconds) has elapsed, as:

```
TimeConstrained[Eigenvalues@RandomReal[1, {5000, 5000}], 1]
Out[1]= $Aborted
```

On the other hand, if memory is the one that blows up first, you can wrap it in `MemoryConstrained` to abort when a certain amount of bytes have been consumed:

```
MemoryConstrained[Range /@ Range[100], 1000]
Out[2]= $Aborted
```

Comment: For some reason TimeConstrained either doesn't work for me or I don't understand how it works ... For example, I want something like:
TimeConstrained[  For[i = 1, i < 100000, i++, Print[i]]  , 1]
to actually stop evaluating after one second. Instead it takes about ten seconds, even tho it only prints to about 1800 before aborting ... Is there a way to actually make THE ENTIRE process take one second?

Comment: @Solarmew `TimeConstrained` is for kernel evaluations, whereas in your example, the "time consuming" part or what you see as a long pause is because the front end is trying to finish printing and displaying all the numbers that were processed in that 1 second. Try this, for example: `TimeConstrained[For[i = 1, i < 100000, i++, Pause[10]], 1]` — this aborts in 1 second. I don't think it is possible to do what you want (i.e. the printing to also stop), but printing output to console in a `For` loop is not a good practice anyway.

Comment: @Solarmew Instead, if you would like to see the progress, try modifying your code to something like the following: `max = 10000000;
Dynamic@ProgressIndicator[i/max]` and then in a different cell: `TimeConstrained[For[i = 1, i < max, i++, Null], 1]`. You should see the progress bar increase and then stop after 1 second.

Answer (score 12):

You can put your calculation inside `TimeConstrained`. However in your case, probably the better idea is to restrict the used memory. That's done with `MemoryConstrained`.

If you don't want to figure out the available memory yourself, see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/459/129) for how to do it automatically.

For example this terminates a calculation if the calculation needs more than 1 GB of memory:

```
MemoryConstrained[Simplify[complicatedExpression],1024^3]
```

This only constrains the simplification, but gives back the original expression if the evaluation fails:

```
MemoryConstrained[Simplify[#],1024^3,#]&[complicatedExpression]
```

This stops evaluation after one hour:

```
TimeConstrained[Simplify[complicatedExpression],3600]
```

Answer (score 1):

I will provide two function in my `init.m` for the answer.This code can help your memory remain at least 3% to avoid crash:

```
$Pre = Function[expr, 
  MemoryConstrained[expr, 
   Round[Last[
       ReadList[
        "!wmic OS get FreePhysicalMemory"]]*1024 - .03 $SystemMemory],
    Print[Style["\[WarningSign]", 28, Red], 
    Style["Memory limit exceeded and Computation aborted!", 15, 
     Red]]], {HoldAll}]
```

And this function can make your `Notebook` like as a baby(Thanks [C. E.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/731/c-e) for [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/131016/21532)) or use `` Internal`Restart[] ``:

```
System`Restart := 
 Block[{$ContextPath}, Needs["Utilities`CleanSlate`"]; 
  Quiet[Remove["`*"]]; 
  Utilities`CleanSlate`CleanSlate[Verbose -> False]; 
  FrontEndTokenExecute /@ {"SelectAll", "Clear"};]
```