# Reuse a dynamic list

Tags: list-manipulation, dynamic, broken-code

Consider this `Dynamic` list

```
Slider[Dynamic@i, {Range[2, 10]}]
MapThread[DirectedEdge, Gather[##] & /@ (Range[#] & /@ Dynamic@i)]
```

The error is

> List expected at position 2 in `MapThread[...]`

. Although the output given by the function is correct:

```
MapThread[DirectedEdge, {{1}, {2}}]
(* {1 -> 2} *)
```

**Edit:**

The purpose of the list creating above is to create a list being exploited by `Graph`:

```
DynamicModule[{p = {{0, 0}, {2, 2}}, i = 2},    
 Grid[{
    {Dynamic[DirectedEdge @@ Range@i],
     Dynamic@N@Round[MousePosition["Graphics"], 0.5]},
    {(Dynamic@Thread[{{DirectedEdge @@ Range@i}, {p}}]), 
     EventHandler[Dynamic@Graph[{DirectedEdge @@ Range@i},
        VertexCoordinates -> p, PlotRange -> 5, GridLines -> Automatic,
        Frame -> True, 
        FrameTicks -> All], "MouseDown" :>
    {(AppendTo[p, N@Round[MousePosition["Graphics"], 0.5]];),++i}]}
      }, Frame -> All]]
```

[image]

With at the top the construction of the `DirectedEdge` and the location of the mouse, at the bottom my attempt to see what should the list look like in order to be replaced in

```
Graph[{#1},VertexCoordinates -> #2]
```

Once again I assume that it's a `Dynamic` issue.

Comment: You say: `this simple code here`. No. This code is not simple. If it was simple, you would have seen the problem allready ;). In cases like these, I take break the code apart, try each piece on its own to make sure it works ok, then build things back piece by piece. And try to spread things out a little. This always works.

Comment: I second what @Nasser says but in this case you also need to realize that `Dynamic` doesn't evaluate. It has the HoldFirst attribute and is only evaluated in the front end; while it looks in the front end like you're passing a list you're really passing `Dynamic[list]` to `MapThread` and that's a no go.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but then how to pass the `List` instead of the `Dynamic[List]`?

Comment: Take `Dynamic` outside `MapThread`. Or use the sam trick which you unconsciously used with `Range` :)

Comment: Thanks all of you! :D Got it now! Should I delete the question?

Comment: Is your expected result `1->2->..->i`?

Comment: @Kuba indeed it is, dynamically constructing a `Graph`

Comment: @Öskå Well, you could answer the Q yourself instead of deleting it.

Comment: I'll let Kuba or Anon answer it. I just don't know if it can help others or if it's a too "basic" mistake.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [(5817)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5817/121)  Also related: [(2972)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2972/121)

Comment: ``CalculateUnits`UnitCommonSymbols`*oint*``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "[...] generally the price of dynamic updating is change of Head." - Vitaliy Kaurov

so

```
Range[5]
Range[Dynamic@5]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
> Range::range: Range specification in Range[5] does not have appropriate bounds. >>
> Range[5]
> ```

but, intentonaly or not, you've passed with `Range`and `Gather` because of `Map` :) and the error was generated by `MapThread` not earlier.

For the record, maybe it is due to the context and you have to use `MapThread` but in this particular case the following code is shorter:

```
Dynamic[DirectedEdge @@ Range@i]
```

---

If you need to use `MapThread` and create lists in form `{{1},...` then you may use `Array`:

```
Array[{#} &, 5]
```

> ```
> {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}}
> ```

---

You can stick with *getting into* `Dynamic Head` with `Map` if you want, just be consistent to the end: ;)

```
Slider[Dynamic@i, {Range[2, 10]}]

MapThread[DirectedEdge, #] & /@ (Array[{#} &, #] & /@ Dynamic@i)
```

**Edit**

Issue from the edit is because of inappropriate syntax, you can not specify `Graph` with sequence of numbers longer then two in `DirectedEdges`, they should be coupled:

```
Graph[ DirectedEdge @@@ Partition[Range@i, 2, 1] ...
```

Comment: `DirectedEdge @@ Range@i` is indeed shorter, thank you!

Comment: @Öskå I'm glad it helped, this was interesting because I've checked couple of things I wasn't sure :)

Comment: Although I'm having an other problem now, dealing with `Dynamic` again (on the same matter). Sould I edit the question or ask a new one? (I assume it has to do with the same trick, but can't figure out).

Comment: @Öskå and an edit to your question if it is closely related, I will edit my answer if I know the solution :)

Comment: Edited, hope that it's clear enough.

Comment: @Öskå it was about syntax, I'm dissappointed :P

Comment: Ah? I spent hours on a syntax error..? I'm disapointing myself too :( BUT thank you! :)