# NonlinearModelFit inside Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, broken-code

I can't understand why this behavior with my code... I'm trying to visually adjust the best parameters to fit my model, everything is working fine, less the part of adjusting the model.

```
WRCFit[data_] := Manipulate[

  Dynamic@
   Switch[dataa, data1, 
    Show[ListLogLinearPlot[dataa, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True], 
     LogLinearPlot[model[h], {h, 0.001, 20000}]],
    data2, 
    Show[ListPointPlot3D[
      Transpose[{Log[dataa[[All, 1]]], dataa[[All, 2]], 
        dataa[[All, 3]]}], PlotRange -> All, 
      PlotTheme -> "Scientific"], 
     Plot3D[model[Exp@h, Ds], {h, Log@0.001, Log@20000}, {Ds, 1, 2}]]],

  Row[{Control@{{dataa, data1, "Type"}, {data1 -> "Data 1", 
       data2 -> "Data 2"}, PopupMenu},

    Control@{{model, m1, "Model"}, {m1 -> "Model 1", m2 -> "Model 2", 
       m3 -> "Model 3"}, PopupMenu}}],

  Button["Fit", 
   Dynamic@Switch[model, m1, 
     NonlinearModelFit[data1, 
      model[h], {{HoldForm@r, Dynamic@r}, {HoldForm@s, 
        Dynamic@s}, {HoldForm@a, Dynamic@a}, {HoldForm@n, Dynamic@n}},
       h],
     m2, NonlinearModelFit[data1, 
      model[h], {{HoldForm@r, Dynamic@r}, {HoldForm@s, 
        Dynamic@s}, {HoldForm@h0, Dynamic@h0}, {HoldForm@l, 
        Dynamic@l}}, h]]],

  Dynamic@Switch[model,
    m1, Column[{Control@{{r, 0.1}, 0, 1}, Control@{{s, 0.5}, 0, 1}, 
      Control@{{a, 20}, 0, 30}, Control@{{n, 1.2}, 1, 2}}],
    m2, Column[{Control@{{r, 0.1}, 0, 1}, Control@{{s, 0.5}, 0, 1}, 
      Control@{{h0, 0.2}, 0.001, 3}, Control@{l, 0.01, 2}}], m3, 
    Column[{Control@{{r, 0.1}, 0, 1}, Control@{{Dss, 2.65}, 2, 3}, 
      Control@{{a, 20}, 0, 30}, Control@{{n0, 1.2}, -2, 2}, 
      Control@{{n1, 1.2}, -2, 2}, Control@{{n2, 1}, -2, 2}}]],

  TrackedSymbols :> {r, s, a, n, h0, l, n0, n1, n2, model, Dss},

  Initialization :> {
    m1[h_] := r + (s - r)/(1 + (a h)^n)^(1 - 1/n),
    m2[h_] := Piecewise[{{r + (s - r) (h0/h)^l, h > h0}, {s, h < h0}}],
    m3[h_, Ds_] := 
     r + ((1 - Ds/Dss) - 
         r)/(1 + (a h)^(n0 + n1 Ds + n2 Ds^2))^(1 - 
          1/(n0 + n1 Ds + n2 Ds^2)),
    data1 = data[[All, {1, 3}]],
    data2 = data
    }]
```

When I click "Fit", i get this messsage

`` FittedModels`FindNonlinearModelFit::vloc: The variable FE`r$$2126 cannot be localized so that it can be assigned to numerical values. ``

Answer (score 3):

I believe [`HoldForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm.html) cannot be used in the manner you are attempting.  Taking the first example from the [`NonlinearModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html) documentation and adding `HoldForm` causes the same error:

```
data = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {3, 2}, {5, 4}, {6, 4}, {7, 5}};

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, Log[a + b x^2], {HoldForm[a], b}, x];
```

> FittedModels`FindNonlinearModelFit::vloc: The variable a cannot be localized so that it can be assigned to numerical values.

I think you should be using different Symbols entirely for the model.

Comment: I just realized that Dynamic[Some Expression] has the Head Dynamic, not Real or Symbol.

Comment: @user48983 Yes, that's a common trip-up, and I wrote a [pitfalls post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85491/121) on the subject; sorry I didn't think to point that out.  I used to point it out with some regularity, e.g. [(2973)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2973/121), [(5820)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5820/121); I guess I feared sounding like a broken record.

Answer (score 0):

My solution

```
WRCFit[data_] := Manipulate[

  Dynamic@
   Switch[dataa, data1, 
    Show[ListLogLinearPlot[dataa, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True], 
     LogLinearPlot[model[h], {h, 0.001, 20000}]],
    data2, 
    Show[ListPointPlot3D[
      Transpose[{Log[dataa[[All, 1]]], dataa[[All, 2]], 
        dataa[[All, 3]]}], PlotRange -> All, 
      PlotTheme -> "Scientific"], 
     Plot3D[model[Exp@h, Ds], {h, Log@0.001, Log@20000}, {Ds, 1, 2}, 
      MeshShading -> {{None, None}, {None, None}}]]],

  Row[{Control@{{dataa, data1, "Type"}, {data1 -> "Data 1", 
       data2 -> "Data 2"}, PopupMenu},

    Control@{{model, m1, "Model"}, {m1 -> "Model 1", m2 -> "Model 2", 
       m3 -> "Model 3"}, PopupMenu}}],

  Button["Fit", 
   Dynamic@Switch[model, m1, 
     Print@Normal@
       NonlinearModelFit[data1, 
        m1fit, {{r0, r}, {s0, s}, {a0, a}, {n00, n}}, h],
     m2, Print@
      Normal@NonlinearModelFit[data1, 
        m2fit, {{r0, r}, {s0, s}, {h00, h0}, {l0, l}}, h]]],

  Dynamic@Switch[model,
    m1, Column[{Control@{{r, 0.1}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
      Control@{{s, 0.5}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
      Control@{{a, 20}, 0, 30, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
      Control@{{n, 1.2}, 1, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}}],
    m2, Column[{Control@{{r, 0.1}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
      Control@{{s, 0.5}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
      Control@{{h0, 0.2}, 0.001, 3, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
      Control@{l, 0.01, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}}],
    m3, Column[{Control@{{r, 0.1}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
      Control@{{Dss, 2.65}, 2, 3, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
      Control@{{a, 20}, 0, 30, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
      Control@{{n0, 1.2}, -2, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
      Control@{{n1, 1.2}, -2, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
      Control@{{n2, 1}, -2, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}}]],

  TrackedSymbols :> {r, s, a, n, h0, l, n0, n1, n2, model, Dss, r0, 
    s0, a0, n00, h00, l0},

  Initialization :> {
    m1[h_] := r + (s - r)/(1 + (a h)^n)^(1 - 1/n),
    m2[h_] := Piecewise[{{r + (s - r) (h0/h)^l, h > h0}, {s, h < h0}}],
    m3[h_, Ds_] := 
     r + ((1 - Ds/Dss) - 
         r)/(1 + (a h)^(n0 + n1 Ds + n2 Ds^2))^(1 - 
          1/(n0 + n1 Ds + n2 Ds^2)),
    data1 = data[[All, {1, 3}]],
    data2 = data,
    m1fit = r0 + (s0 - r0)/(1 + (a0 h)^n00)^(1 - 1/n00),
    m2fit = 
     Piecewise[{{r0 + (s0 - r0) (h00/h)^l0, h > h00}, {s0, h < h00}}],
     Dynamic@
     Switch[model, 
      m1, {r -> Dynamic@r, s -> Dynamic@s, a -> Dynamic@a, 
       n -> Dynamic@n},
      m2, {r -> Dynamic@r, s -> Dynamic@s, h0 -> Dynamic@h0, 
       l -> Dynamic@l}]
    }]

WRCFit[data]
```

But it's far from being a good code.