# Different results with Plot option "Evaluated" in V9 and V10

Tags: plotting

Consider this example:

```
Plot[Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 2}], {x, 0, 10}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"n=1", "n=2"}, Evaluated -> True]
```

The results in MMA v9 & V10 are:

**V9:**

[image]

**V10:**

[image]

Any idea why V10 can't pick up all PlotLegends?
Thanks.

Comment: Probably a(nother) bug

Comment: `Evaluate` does work: `Plot[Evaluate@Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 2}], {x, 0, 10}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"n=1", "n=2"}]`, which is also a workaround.

Comment: For me it is still undocumented so I would not call it a bug :)

Comment: @Kuba, the case here is V9 and V10 giving two different results. it may be good to call it bug -:)

Comment: @Algohi I can't agree. [Even mod would not ;)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5943/5478)

Answer (score 3):

I am in the middle of the long process of Tracing this issue.  I don't yet have a patch but I can point to a part of the code that affects this.  The function is:

```
Legending`LegendDump`plotLegendParser
```

Within its long definition we have a piece:

```
Legending`LegendDump`length = Switch[Legending`LegendDump`tag,
  0, Legending`LegendDump`optDimensions,
  _Integer, Legending`LegendDump`optDimensions[[Legending`LegendDump`tag]],
  "Generic", 
  If[Legending`LegendDump`arglength === Null, Switch[Legending`LegendDump`argexp,
    Null, 0,
    _List, Length[Legending`LegendDump`argexp],
    _, 1], Legending`LegendDump`arglength]]
```

This is where the number of functions is determined for the sake of legend generation.  The critical part here is:

```
Length[Legending`LegendDump`argexp]
```

Which in the case of the example in the question expands to:

```
Length[{HoldForm[Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 2}]]}]
```

The plot function is being passed unevaluated (held by `HoldForm`) to `` Legending`LegendDump`plotLegendParser ``, which is exactly the sort of problem I expected.  I have confirmed that replacing `Length[. . .]` in this definition with `2` causes the legend to be draw properly for this example, but I have not yet figured out how to determine that value automatically.

This answer is a work in progress but I wanted to get this down before I forget it.  It may also serve as a starting point for anyone else who wishes to tackle the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Not really an idea or insight, but a workaround (on 10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 10, 2014);

```
Plot[Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 2}], {x, 0, 10},  
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue},  
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{Red, Blue}, {"n=1", "n=2"}],  
 Evaluated -> True]
```

[image]

The "Help" is not really a help:

[image]
[image]

except the workaround I can not offer an explanation for this behavior.