# Evaluate and PlotLegends

Tags: plotting, legending, hold

Related to this question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/plot-draws-list-of-curves-in-same-color-when-not-using-evaluate). I dont understand why Evaluated->True does not behave properly when also using PlotLegends. For example, running the code below

```
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + 2 y;
Plot[Array[f[x, #1] &, 3, {1, 2}], {x, 1, 5}, PlotLegends -> Table[x, {x, 1, 3}], Evaluated -> True]
```

will give [image: result with only Evaluated option]
which does not give the correct Legends (same thing happens if I add Evaluate before the PlotLegend list (Table[x, {x, 1, 3}]).

However, if I add Evaluate before the plotting argument, then it works fine:

```
Plot[Evaluate@Array[f[x, #1] &, 3, {1, 2}], {x, 1, 5}, PlotLegends -> Table[x, {x, 1, 3}]]
```

[image: With Evaluated Option]

Clearly, Evaluate and Evaluated works differently when there is PlotLegends. Why?

Comment: If relevant, Im using Mathematica 12.0.0.0 on Mac OS X

Comment: `Evaluated` is not a valid `Plot` option. It should be colored red to indicate that, but it does not. Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: `Evaluated` is recognized normally by `Plot`, although it is not documented. There were some discussions [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56060/why-the-variable-scope-is-not-local-when-using-evaluate-to-plot-multicurve/56064#56064), or [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69104/different-results-with-plot-option-evaluated-in-v9-and-v10), it is very useful in some cases. Second link gives a workaround: using defined `PlotStyle` and `LineLegend`.