# How to prevent long evaluation and infinite loops

Tags: evaluation, infinite-loop

I'm new to this, so sometimes I accidentally ask Mathematica to do calculations with numbers so big that it can't handle it and it immediately freezes my laptop to the point where there's nothing I can do ([alt]+[.] doesn't work) but brute force restart it :(
I tried using `TimeConstrained` but it didn't appear to do anything for my case.
Is there any way to abort evaluation it if starts slowing down my computer so much that it's about to freeze?

Comment: If the computer freezes it might be a problem with memory, in that case [there are solutions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57905/may-i-restrict-caching-to-disk-when-memory-runs-low). Most operations in *Mathematica* use only one core and modern computers typically have four cores, so that should not cause your computer to become unresponsive. If it is not unresponsive you can simply shut down the kernel to immediately disrupt your evaluation by going to Evaluation -> Quit Kernel in the menu. (Restarting the kernel means you lose all information in your session.)

Comment: I see someone said
MemoryConstrained[yourCode, memoryLimit, actionOnMemoryLimitOverflow]
might be the answer.
In this case, do you have a recommendation for how much memory to allocate?
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3610QM CPU @ 2.30 GHz
8.00 GB (7.89 GB usable)

Comment: Slightly below 7.89 GB.