# Return partial result when MemoryConstrained aborts NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, evaluation, kernel

I use `NDSolve` to solve a large set (~400) of coupled ODEs. Sometimes, the memory (~4GB) gets filled up, and my computer becomes impossible to work with, because it spends too much time writing to swap and the process can only be killed violently by the OS.

I circumvent this by using `MemoryConstrained`, but when the solver reaches the memory limit it is simply aborted and does not return the solution it obtained so far. Is there a way to obtain this solution (much like what happens when the solver encounters a singularity or reaches `MaxSteps`)?

Note: using a hack of the form

```
 StepMonitor :> If[MemoryInUse[]>...,...]
```

results in serious computational overhead.

Comment: Not wishing to be facetious, but if possible, I think it would be worthwhile to install more memory (or use a computer with more memory already installed). Personally I prefer to use *Mathematica* with a minimum of 8GB.

Comment: I'd love to know the answer to this. No matter how much memory I am given, I always manage to use it all up with Mathematica.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I have already ordered 16GB of RAM, but I think this problem is general and interesting enough to have a hardware-independent answer.

Comment: Strongly related: "[Aborting evaluation when the memory exceeds a certain limit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2789/280)" and "[How to find out the (current) free memory on the system?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/164/280)."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Borrowing from an example of [`WhenEvent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WhenEvent.html#38207198) from the documentation in which a `Button` is used to stop the integration, I came up with this.

```
ClearAll[ndsolveMemConstrained];
SetAttributes[ndsolveMemConstrained, HoldFirst];
ndsolveMemConstrained::mlim = "Memory used `` exceeded limit ``.";
ndsolveMemConstrained[(nd_: NDSolve | NDSolveValue)[eqns_, rest___], bytes_] :=
 Module[{sol, stop, task, mstart},
  mstart = MemoryInUse[];
  stop = False;
  task = RunScheduledTask[
    stop = (ndsolve`mem = MemoryInUse[] - mstart) > bytes,
    0.2];
  sol = nd[Append[eqns,
           WhenEvent[stop,
            Message[ndsolveMemConstrained::mlim, ndsolve`mem, bytes];
            "StopIntegration"]],
     rest];
  RemoveScheduledTask[task];
  sol]
```

As a baseline, here is an example DE from the documentation:

```
NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x], t, t] == D[u[t, x], x, x], 
   u[0, x] == Exp[-10 x^2], Derivative[1, 0][u][0, x] == 0, 
   u[t, -10] == u[t, 10]}, u, {t, 0, 100}, {x, -10, 10}, 
  Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {10.969550,InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,100.},{\[Ellipsis],-10.,10.,\[Ellipsis]}},<>]} *)
```

When the memory is not exceeded, it takes about the same amount of time:

```
ndsolveMemConstrained[
  NDSolveValue[{
    D[u[t, x], t, t] == D[u[t, x], x, x], u[0, x] == Exp[-10 x^2], 
    Derivative[1, 0][u][0, x] == 0, u[t, -10] == u[t, 10]},
   u, {t, 0, 100}, {x, -10, 10}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"],
  8000000] // AbsoluteTiming
ndsolve`mem

(* {10.962278, InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 100.}, {..., -10., 10.,...}}, <>]} *)
(* 6992160 *)
```

When the memory limit is exceeded, there is frequently an extra warning message generated.  I assume it has to do with where the solver is when `stop` is checked.  (It's odd that it doesn't *always* produce the convergence warning.)

```
ndsolveMemConstrained[
  NDSolveValue[{
    D[u[t, x], t, t] == D[u[t, x], x, x], u[0, x] == Exp[-10 x^2], 
    Derivative[1, 0][u][0, x] == 0, u[t, -10] == u[t, 10]},
   u, {t, 0, 100}, {x, -10, 10}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"],
  4000000] // AbsoluteTiming
ndsolve`mem
```

> NDSolveValue::evcvmit: Event location failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations between t = 56.32617731294334`and t = 56.50060870314276`. >>
>
> ndsolveMemConstrained::mlim: Memory used 4158544 exceeded limit 4000000.

```
(* {5.595887, InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 56.3262}, {..., -10., 10.,...}}, <>]} *)
(* 4047584 *)
```

You can also monitor memory usage if the following is executed before `ndsolveMemConstrained`.

```
Dynamic @ ndsolve`mem

(* 6992160 *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method I found for a different problem which could probably be adapted to yours.

```
{fit, steps} = 
  Reap[TimeConstrained[
    FindFit[ztp, {convolutionModel, k > 1 && r0 > 0 && r1 > 0}, 
     convolutionParameters, t, Method -> Automatic, 
     StepMonitor :> Sow[{r0, r1, k}]], 10]];
```

You should be able to change `TimeConstrained` to `MemoryConstrained` with the appropriate limit.  For my problem, fit returns `$Aborted` if the constraint is met then I get the  best result at that point with

```
If[fit === $Aborted, steps[[1]][[-1]]
```

Comment: The code seems to have disappeared here is the example again.  {fit, steps} = 
  Reap[TimeConstrained[
    FindFit[ztp, {convolutionModel, k > 1 && r0 > 0 && r1 > 0}, 
     convolutionParameters, t, Method -> Automatic, 
     StepMonitor :> Sow[{r0, r1, k}]], 10]];