# Why does MemoryConstrained not abort when memory limit is exceeded?

Tags: memory

I thought I had an idea that might lead to an answer to @yohbs' [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16031/return-partial-result-when-memoryconstrained-aborts-ndsolve), but as I was trying to check out the usage of `MemoryConstrained[expr,b,failexpr]`, I discovered behavior I did not expect.
The following aborts immediately; neither `k` nor `t` are set. (Please don't worry about the `Rule` -- I added `"Abort"->` merely to distinguish an aborted computation):

```
Clear[t,k];
MemoryConstrained[Table[k = j; t[j] = Range[10j], {j, 1000}],
  2199, "Aborted" -> Table[t[j], {j,k}]]
```

> Out[2]= Aborted->Table[t[j],{j,k}]

I guess that it takes more than 2199 bytes to build the `Table` expression and it does not even evaluate one iteration.  If the limit is raised one byte to 2200, then the command does not abort at all.

```
Clear[t,k];
MemoryConstrained[Table[k = j; t[j] = Range[10j], {j,1000}],
  2200, "Aborted" -> Table[t[j], {j, k}]] // Short
```

> Out[4]= //Short= {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},<<998>>,{1,2,<<9997>>,10000}}

As you can see below, 41M were used to store the result, not to mention the other 41M stored in `t[_]`.

```
ByteCount[%]
```

> Out[5]= 41277832

The last list, `Range[10000]`, is stored in `t[1000]` and exceeds the limit of 2200 bytes:

```
ByteCount[t[1000]]
```

> Out[6]= 80144

Any `Range[n]` with `n` equal to 256 or more causes an abort:

```
MemoryConstrained[Range[256], 2200]
```

> Out[7]= $Aborted

```
ByteCount[Range[256]]
```

> Out[8]= 2160

```
ByteCount[Range[257]]
```

> Out[9]= 2416

(It is believable that there are more than 40 bytes of overhead in computing `Range` and that the chunking of memory causes the 256 byte jump, although these are just a random stabs at an explanation.)

Does someone know how to make `MemoryConstrained` abort when the limit is 2200?  Or can someone explain when memory request counts toward the `MemoryContrained` limit?

**Addendum**

Thanks for the help so far.  I'm on Mac OS 10.8.2, Mma 9.0.0, slightly old MacBook Pro (~2008), 6GB RAM.

I restarted Mathematica and tried again.  Same result.  However, changing the limit on the iterator `j` from 1000 to 100 got it work.  Strange.

```
Clear[t,k];
MemoryConstrained[Table[k = j; t[j] = Range[10 j], {j, 100}],
  2200, "Aborted" -> Table[t[j], {j, k}]] // Short
```

> Aborted->{{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},{1,<<18>>,20},t[3]}

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce with 8.0.4 linux 64bit. What OS are you on? I have to up the memory limit to about $3 \cdot 10^7$ or it will abort.

Comment: Which version of *Mathematica* do you use? There was a lot of problems with `MemoryConstrained` before version 8 was released. ["For version 8 the memory allocator has been rewritten and improved. (What a small sentence for such a huge endeavor and such a fine execution.)" (Oliver Ruebenkoenig)](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/oWWRbY8brBc/fPM5525uBzIJ)

Comment: I'm running 9.0.0 on OSX 10.8.2.

Comment: Could this have to do with `Table` auto compiling for the 1000? What happens if you play with `SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> {"TableCompileLength" -> 0}]` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems system dependent. 
On Mathematica 8.0, WinXP:

```
Clear[t, k];
MemoryConstrained[Table[k = j; t[j] = Range[10 j], {j, 1000}], 2 10^7,
   "Aborted" -> Table[t[j], {j, k}]] // Short
(*
-> Aborted->{{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},<<981>>,t[983]}
*)
```

While

```
Clear[t, k];
MemoryConstrained[Table[k = j; t[j] = Range[10 j], {j, 1000}], 2 10^8,
   "Aborted" -> Table[t[j], {j, k}]] // Short
(*
-> {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},<<998>>,{1,2,3,4,5,6,9988>>,9995,9996,9997,9998,9999,10000}}
*)
```

Comment: I get the same result on Mac OS 10.8.2 using either Mathematica 8.0.4 or 9.0

Comment: @belisarius.  Thanks for looking at it.  As far as I can tell, it is a system issue.  I'll file a tech. report with them.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Ok. Good luck with that!